# Find difference of two array lists in JAVA spring mvc

Tags: java, arrays, spring-mvc, arraylist

I have two arraylists and will like to return the difference of the two. Below is my code snippet:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/unpaidfees", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public List<Fee> unpaid(@PathVariable("studentid") Long studentid){
    Transactions tr = transServ.instalmentalstd(studentid);
    List<Fee> allfees = feesServ.allFees();

    if(tr != null){
        List<Fee> paidfees = transServ.paidfees(tr.getTranxid());
        allfees.removeAll(paidfees);
    }

    return allfees;     
}
```

In summary.
I have an array list which contains all fees :

```
List<Fee> allfees = feesServ.allFees();
```

And the second arraylist which contains paid fees:

```
List<Fee> paidfees = transServ.paidfees(tr.getTranxid());
```

I will like to return a list of fees present in allfees only but not in paidfees. Please advise on how to achieve this or a better way to go about this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi Sotirios Delimanolis. Thanks for your time. However, its not a duplicate because I tried the question you referred me to but it returned all fees and didnt work for me.

Comment: The issue was with absence of equals() in the Fee class/model. Incase you are reading this, dont suffer same way I have for 3 days and nights. Dont forget to add equals() and Hashcode to your entity else all the suggestions wont work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ArrayList#removeAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))):

```
// Copy all fees
List<Fee> difference = new ArrayList<>(allFees);

// Keep only fees that are different
difference.removeAll(paidfees);
```

Comment: That's intersection of the two

Comment: I was not down voted, btw

Comment: @AliDehghani Thanks for pointing the intersection thing, I  tripped for a second.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-):

```
List<Fee> unpaidFees = new ArrayList<>(allfees);
unpaidFees.removeAll(paidfees);
```